# Unable to add ASP.NET Component in IIS 7.5 using Windows 7 SP1

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

I have tried to add ASP.NET Component in IIS 7.5 From the Control Panel, click Programs and then click Turn Windows features on or off which is listed under Programs and Features, Checked IIS options. While it is saving getting following error :

**An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed**

Comment: You might follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues But an in-place Windows installation should be quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this issue may occurs because a duplicate Internet Server API (ISAPI) filter is detected when you try to install the ASP.NET feature.

I suggest you could try below steps to reinstall the asp.net:

1.Open  IIS management console

2.Expand the local computer node, double-click ISAPI Filters, and then remove all the ASP.NET filters that are listed.

[image]

3.Re-install the asp.net in the control panel

Comment: From where I will get it : **Expand the local computer node, double-click ISAPI Filters, and then remove all the ASP.NET filters that are listed.** I am using Windows 7 SP1

Comment: I mean the root of the IIS management console. See my update answer.

Comment: Still Facing same issue :(

Comment: I have checked CBS log file getting like :
Unable to open Driver key: SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET_2.0.50727\Performance

Comment: I suggest you could check the event viewer logs again and if possible you could upload some etl files for the event logs. Notice: You should make sure the logs doesn't contain any personal information.